# Can this state be expressed as a product of three one-qubit states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

For the following three qubit state:
[image]

This state **can't** be represented as a product of three single qubit's. The answer is that there are correlations between the three qubits, which I do not understand the meaning of. Please can someone provide further context/explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you measure all three qubits in the $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}$.

Further, assume the state can be written as a product state.

Now imagine that for the first two qubits, you get the result $|00\rangle$.  Then, you know that the third qubit *must* give the result $|1\rangle$. Since it is in a product state with the other qubits, it means it must have been in the state $|1\rangle$ from the very beginning.

Now imagine that for the first two qubits, you get the result $|01\rangle$. Then, via the same reasoning, the third qubit must have been in the state $|0\rangle$ from the beginning.

But this is a contradiction. Thus, the system cannot have been in a product state to start with.

---

The reason for this problems are the correlations between the qubits: if you measure 00, the 3rd qubit must give 1, while if you measure 01, the third qubit must give 0.  This means that there are correlations between the measurement outcomes on the individual qubits, and this is what makes it possible to describe the qubits as individual product states, which which case the outcomes of measurements of the three qubits must be entirely independent.